# No field mMaxWidth in class Landroid/widget/ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, universal-image-loader

I used `UniversalImageLoader` (`displayImage` method) for loading image

But it throws `NoSuchFieldException` exception :

> No field mMaxWidth in class Landroid/widget/ImageView; (declaration of
>   'android.widget.ImageView' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)

How to fix ?

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/1343. Move to glide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many researches, It seems that the bug is shown in android 10 or greater.
as discussed below :

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/1343

So I moved to Glide library until it's later fixes.

Comment: Works fine as expected, since 2019 I facing this issue while loading the image in recycler view.

Answer (score 14):

Issue fixed but not updated in gradle version.

**Solution 1 :**

For now don't use

`implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'`

or

```
.jar file
```

You can download library as zip and add manually as module.
I am facing same issue, but this is worked in my case.

For file changes you can check this commit: [f6a9615](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/commit/f6a9615868482672c3630cb7db6dcf43391e80de)

**Solution 2 :**

You can use this commit using JitPack:

In your build.gradle (app level) file, add:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

And replace

`implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'`
with:

```
implementation 'com.github.nostra13:Android-Universal-Image-Loader:f6a9615868482672c3630cb7db6dcf43391e80de'
```

Comment: This solution work and is same as this [comment](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/1356) in GitHub.